# batch script to move files from one server to another older than 45 days

Tags: windows, batch-file

can someone help to write windows batch script to move files older than 45 days from one system to another whcih is added in network and domain.

Example : 
Move files older than 45 days from folders A, B, C of System1 to A, B, C of System 2.

I have tried running below code but it is working fine if my source and destination is same server but it is not working when source and destination is diff server.Server2 Folder i.e A,B are shared folders and Server1 have access to it

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions
net use m: "\\System2\d$\A\"
Forfiles -p \\System1\d$\A -s -m *.* -d -45 -c "cmd /c move /y @FILE m: & echo %Date% Source File: @PATH to \\System2\d$\A\">>D:\Test\logfile.txt
net use /delete m:
net use n: "\\System2\d$\B\"
Forfiles -p \\System1\d$\B -s -m *.* -d -45 -c "cmd /c move /y @FILE n: & echo %Date% Source File: @PATH to \\System2\d$\B\">>D:\Test\logfile.txt
net use /delete m:
GOTO :eof
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't think anyone want to do the work for you. Try yourself writing such a batch file and come back when you have specific questions why something does not work (as expected).

Comment: Indent your code lines by four spaces and SO will format them as code, making them much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `robocopy.exe`.  It is part of standard installations since Vista/Server 2008.  It has command line parameters that can be used to select files of certain ages.  Type `robocopy /?` for details.

Comment: Thanks Nate, i am now working on robocopy, mean while i have written script which is working fine for single system but while transfering files to other system it is not working as expected.